# Add Instana traceId to spring boot logging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, instana

I have an application landscape where we use Instana agents to monitor and trace the applications.
To be able to correlate an application log to a trace I'd like to add the traceId from Instana into our logs.
Now I've tried to add spring-cloud-sleuth and I see some traceId and spanIds in the logs, but these aren't the Instana ones.
The trace and span are included in the headers of the request with `x-instana-t` and `x-instana-s`. But I don't see a way to inject these headers into spring-cloud-sleuth.

I've [read and tried as described in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-change-context-propagation), but apparently the headers can be empty, resulting in NPEs while trying to use the `HexCodec`.

Question in short: How can I make sleuth use the instana trace headers?

Answer (score 1):

1. Instana Java tracer will add `instana.trace.id` to logs for the supported frameworks.
   Please refer: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/instana-observability/current?topic=technologies-monitoring-java-virtual-machine#logging
2. To get the current spanId and traceId from the monitored application, you can use Instana Trace SDK. Refer: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/instana-observability/current?topic=references-java-trace-sdk
3. Use this guide for configuring sdk - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/instana-observability/current?topic=references-java-trace-sdk#using-the-instana-java-sdk
4. After configuring sdk, you can use the below two APIs to get the Ids
   String traceId = SpanSupport.traceId();
   String spanId = SpanSupport.spanId();
5. You will get the ids if there is an active request getting processed.